# Background overlay doesn't go away when I close the off-canvas sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [BigSlide JS](http://ascott1.github.io/bigSlide.js/) to create an off-canvas sidebar. The plugin doesn't come with a feature to add a background overlay whenever the off-canvas sidebar is called into action, so I added my own.

This is the icon that shows the sidebar on click

```
<div class="icon menu1 menu-link">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

And this is how I initialize

```
$('.menu-link').bigSlide({
    menu: '#off-canvas-menu',
    menuWidth: '270px',
    easyClose: true
});
```

Now for the background overlay I created a new html div and placed it at the top of the content div

```
<div class="site-overlay"></div>
```

Then I added its CSS

```
.site-overlay {
    display: none;
}
.menu-open .site-overlay {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9998;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -webkit-animation: fade 500ms;
    animation: fade 500ms;
}
```

And I added a JS function to add the class `menu-open` to the `body` whenever the div with the classes `.menu-link` gets clicked on

```
$('.menu-link').click(function() {
    $('body').addClass('menu-open');
});
```

But now when I close the sidebar, the background overlay remains and I have no idea how to make it go away.

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/v1w532d3/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try doing:

```
$('.menu-link').bigSlide({
   menu: '#off-canvas-menu',
   menuWidth: '270px',
   easyClose: true,
   afterOpen: function(){
      $('body').addClass('menu-open');
   },
   afterClose: function(){
    $('body').removeClass('menu-open');
   }
});
```

and remove:

```
$('.menu-link').click(function() {
   $('body').addClass('menu-open');
});
```

as you don't seem to need it since you use bigSlide for the off-canvas functionality.

See bigSlide's documentation here for all available options: https://github.com/ascott1/bigSlide.js